# ionic2 - create function only when user clicks "close" inside Toast

Tags: javascript, angular, toast, ionic2, undo

I created a toast with ionic2 (+ angular2 with javascript, not typescript), where the user removes a item from the list.

So far so good, now I want to add a button `Undo` (replace Close by Undo) inside the toast to put it back on list and at the same time Dismiss the toast.

My code so far:

```
archiveItem(item) {
    let toast = Toast.create({
        message: 'Item archived.',
        duration: 2000,
        showCloseButton: true,
        closeButtonText: 'Undo',
        dismissOnPageChange: true,
    });

    var index = this.items.indexOf(item);
    this.items.splice(index, 1); //remove the item


    toast.onDismiss(() => {
        console.log('Dismissed toast');
        this.items.splice(index, 0, item); //put back the item on right place
    });


    this.nav.present(toast);
}
```

When I click `Undo`, the item returns to the list, the problem is that if I don't click it, it goes back to the list as well.

I suppose I need to create another function to the `Undo`, but I don't know how to do that, and Ionic2 DOCS don't talk about it...

Thank you :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:**

Try this:

```
 toast.onDismiss((data, role) => {    
        console.log('Dismissed toast');
        if (role== "close") {
           this.items.splice(index, 0, item); //put back the item on right place
        }
    });
```

edit: renamed parameters for clarity

Comment: Wow, it works, thank you! Could you explain me what's "rejected == "close" ?

Comment: It's not documented, If you look at the code of the toast (in your node_modules) you'll see that it passes (null,role) to the viewcontroller's onDismiss callback. Role is 'close' when the toast is dismissed from the button. Be aware that since this is not documented, this could break in future versions.

Comment: got it! Thank you so much. I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: in ionic2 `onDismiss` is renamed to `onDidDismiss`

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 4 this is what worked for me:

```html
    toast.onDidDismiss().then(val => {
      if (val.role== "cancel") {
       //Action
     }
  });
```